# javascript in master page to be run only when a document library is opened

Tags: document-library, custom-masterpage, system-master-page

I already found a similar post here:

[register-javascript-for-document-library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91324/register-javascript-for-document-library)

But instead of adding a content/script editor to every document library, as suggested, I'd prefer to add my code to the system master page and have it triggered only when a document library gets opened. Does any one have a solution for this?
The code I developed is working great when I put it in a script editor, now how can I make it run from the master page only on document libraries?

Answer (score 0):

you maybe get Doc. library by checking the url if it contains `Forms/AllItems.aspx` and then execute your code

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With your solution though I cannot create custom views for libraries... What if, for instance, I switch from AllItems.aspx to Custom.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem. Here's my solution:

```
        if ( ctx != null && ctx.listBaseType == 1) {
            //YOUR CODE HERE
        }
```

This way the code will be executed only if the Sharepoint ctx variable is loaded and the library you open is a Document Library (that means that listBaseType == 1).